# Informacion uso de cubos en Analisys Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas

En resumen necesito algun metodo, query o informe que me pueda dar informacion de que usuarios se conectan a los cubos y con cuanta frecuencia son usados.

Busque informacion por todos lados y no encuentro algo que me sirva para el proposito.

La idea es poder entregar un reporte semanal de uso de estos cubos.

La version de SQL Server que se usa es Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3)

Comment: Hola! Podrías, cuando menos, indicar la versión del software que estás usando? Es una pregunta que pinta útil incluso en su formato actual -demasiado amplia-, así que cualquier cosa que ayude a acotarla puede ayudar.

Comment: @Alfabravo ahi agregue la version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3)

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar, pero no tengo tiempo de crear una respuesta apropiada. https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/analysis-services/instances/log-operations-in-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions